# REPLACE INTO sql query with 2 keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to create a table through phpMyAdmin where I can `REPLACE INTO` a row where two columns match.

I have a table called `channel_data` that has 2 assigned ID's. One for the relevant server (`guild_id`) and one for the relevant data's owner (`owner_id`).

```
REPLACE INTO channel_data (guild_id, owner_id, username, userlimit) 
VALUES ('123456789123456789', '123456789123456789', 'foo', '100');`
```

Above is an example of what I want to achieve but I want it to replace the values of `username` & `userlimit` if a row is found with the same `guild_id` & `owner_id`; but if not - it creates a new row...

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "*2 assigned keys*" ... it's not at all clear what that means. Does that mean two separate UNIQUE KEY constraints? two separate non-unique constraints? or does it mean there's a composite key (two columns in the same UNIQUE index) ?  The actual definition of the table (the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE statement) would go a long ways to *accurately* describing the table. And why a `REPLACE` statement and not an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique multi-column index on the two columns.

```
ALTER TABLE channel_data
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (guild_id, owner_id);
```